# Bash script to find all folders containing a specific file and copy a new file to those folders

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm trying to write a script that will loop through all subfolders of a directory to search for a specific file and then copy a new file to those folders that contain that file.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/Documents
find "$dir" -name Sample.doc -printf "%p\n" | sort -nr | while read -r i; do
  echo "$i"
  done
```

This works to list all the `Sample.doc` files and their folders within the `Documents` folder.

However, I cannot find a way to extract the path from those folders to copy the new file into them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there. You can replace `%p` with `%h` in the `-printf` expression :

> %h : Leading directories of file's name (all but the last element). 
>   If the file name contains no slashes (since it is in the current
>   directory) the %h specifier expands to ".".

so the command would be something like :

```
find "$dir" -name Sample.doc -printf "%h\n" | sort -nr | while read -r i; do cp SomeFile "$i"; done
```

by the way, why is the `sort` part needed ?

Answer (score 0):

The `dirname` command removes the filename from the full path

Answer (score 0):

Using `%h` instead `%p` has already been suggested in another answer, but I'd like to add some improvements to make your code more robust. If, for instance, a matching directory contains a newline character in its name, you will in the best-case end up missing directories and getting some error messages from *cp*. At worst, you might override files anywhere on your system.

So instead, try doing it like this:

```
find "$dir" -name Sample.doc -printf "%h\0" | xargs --null -L1 cp SomeFile
```

The ACSII zero is guaranteed to never show up in any filenames, so unlike `\n` it works as a reliable separator for passing the paths. `--null` tells `xargs` to use the `\0` as a input delimiter. It will then execute the given command (`cp Somefile`) once per item passed through the pipe, while appending the respective item as additional argument.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
for i in "$dir"/**/Sample.doc
do
    cp 'new file' "$(dirname "$i")"/
done
```

In fish:

```
for i in $dir/**Sample.doc
    cp 'new file' (dirname $i)/
end
```